# Virtual /etc/hosts file for wordpress development

Tags: wordpress, web, dns, hosts

I am developping a wordpress website (mywebsite.net) and have two versions:

- A published version (host at a IP adresse xx.xx.xx.xx)
- A local version (host locally at 127.0.0.1)

If I want to switch between the local and the hosted version, I have to change the /etc/hosts file.

Is there another simpler way to switch? I'm thinking for example to a firefox extension which would override the DNS settings: it would allow me to access the published version with Safari and the local with firefox.

I could also use to different dns but it would broke wordpress link which are absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a fake local domain like wordpress.localhost in your hosts file.  I have dozens of these, all running on 127.0.0.1.  The domain is different, but in most PHP apps, that's a simple change if any.  You could also make a local subdomain like dev.mywebsite.net, which could help in some cases.  You mention broken links, but I've found this a great reason to always use relative paths.